# How to run C program in Visual Studio with "parameters"

Tags: c, terminal, console

I'm not sure if "parameters" is the correct term, but I don't know what else to put. I have a C program that displays "Hello World!" in the terminal when I run it. But I have to follow specific steps before I run it. Assuming I am in the correct directory, I first must compile the .c file. In the terminal I type,

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 hello_world.c
```

then to run the program, I type

```
./a.out
```

My question is, how do I run that .c file in Visual studios while using the "gcc -Wall -std=c99". To be honest, I have no ides what "gcc -Wall -std=c99" does exactly, but I have to use it.

Comment: `-Wall` tells the compiler to display the entire message of any error and warning.

Comment: @Tau - Huh?  `-Wall` enables a bunch of warnings. You can see the list [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options). It doesn't affect *how* they're displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gcc -Wall -std=c99` compiles the c file with the c99 standard. I don't know what your exact question is here, but to run both in one command you would need to do: `gcc -Wall -std=c99 && ./a.out`

Comment: How do I compile the c file and run it in visual studio with c99 standard?

Comment: @Z10987654321X The visual studio C compiler doesn't support C99 (Though individual bits of it that are also part of C++ sometimes will work; it depends on your specific code).